# node log4j No output from the console

Tags: node.js, log4j

app.js :

```js
const log4js = require('log4js');

log4js.configure({
  appenders: { app: { type: 'dateFile', filename: './log/', pattern: 'yyyy-MM-dd.log', alwaysIncludePattern: true } },
  categories: { default: { appenders: ['app'], level: 'trace' } }
});

const Logger = log4js.getLogger('app');
Logger.level = 'trace';
Logger.error('log4js start.');
```

run

```
node app.js
```

1. No output from the console, But the file has a record
2. and.  Log file name: `log.2020-02-08.log`, Instead of what I expected `./log/2020-02-08.log`

I don't understand the documentation a bit, hope to help me correct my configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a documentation for output to console: https://github.com/log4js-node/log4js-node/blob/master/docs/console.md.

This is my snippet after appending one more config:

```js
const log4js = require("log4js");

log4js.configure({
  appenders: {
    app: { type: 'dateFile', filename: './log/', pattern: 'yyyy-MM-dd.log', alwaysIncludePattern: true },
    console: { type: "console" }
  },
  categories: { default: { appenders: ["app", "console"], level:
```

Comment: Yes this is the effect i want, but The second problem remains.